# How to include .exe files as zip files while uploading to hosting?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, hosting

I am using windows hosting for My asp.net mvc 4 application. While upload to server .exe files are rejected due to some security reason. Support team suggest me to upload .exe files as zip files. But visual studio 2015 .exe files are inn bin/rosyln folder csc.exe, vb.exe , etc. I hve no idea what is this and how this used. Help me to upload my asp.net application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do either one (your choice):

- look for a host that works with the latest version of ASP.Net which includes `roslyn` compilers (the `exe` files you're seeing), *or*;
- [remove `roslyn` from your ASP.Net application](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/remove-roslyn-support-from-asp-net-project)

You can't just zip them up - your ASP.Net app needs (to execute) them. The 2nd option will likely be your choice with your existing provider if they restrict executables (which is actually more common than those that allow it - particularly if its shared hosting).

Comment: Remove roslyn can affect app functionality?

Comment: @user7013033 Only if you are actually using it.  Removing the Roslyn references and rebuilding should work if you're not actually using Roslyn in your own code.